# Run javascript using echo in php

Tags: javascript, php

I have this code of javascript

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
echo 'document.write('<a style="display:block;width:100%;height:1px;" class="aff-ad-none"></a>');
window.AFF_ONLOAD = window.AFF_ONLOAD || [];window.AFF_ONLOAD.push({lkid:"11",affid:"10",size:"728*90",type:"1",language:"English",web_id:"40",version:110});
var aff_s = document.createElement("script"),aff_h = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];aff_s.charset = "utf-8";aff_s.async = !0;aff_s.src = "https://js.affasi.com/affasi_js.min.js";
aff_h.insertBefore(aff_s, aff_h.firstChild);
</script>';
```

I get Parse error: parse error, expecting `','' or`';''
The error is in this line :
`echo 'document.write('<a style="display:block;width:100%;height:1px;" class="aff-ad-none"></a>');` ....

How do i add single quote in echo command? This should fix the error i guess right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the parentheses `'` with `\` in `document.write()` like this:

```
<?php
echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
echo 'document.write(\'<a style="display:block;width:100%;height:1px;" class="aff-ad-none"></a>\');
window.AFF_ONLOAD = window.AFF_ONLOAD || [];
window.AFF_ONLOAD.push({lkid:"11",affid:"10",size:"728*90", type:"1",language:"English",web_id:"40",version:110});
var aff_s = document.createElement("script"),aff_h = 
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];aff_s.charset = "utf-8";aff_s.async = 
!0;aff_s.src = "https://js.affasi.com/affasi_js.min.js";
aff_h.insertBefore(aff_s, aff_h.firstChild);
</script>';
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer as well. It seems that i get the correct output and i have no error but the content of the javascript does not show up in the webpage! Weird!

Comment: anyway i accept this answer it works with the new code generated probably the previous content was offline.

Answer (score 1):

- you  you need to  escape charcter (the best way)

`echo 'document.write(\'<astyle="display:block;width:100%;height:1px;" class="aff-ad-none"></a>\'); '`

- you  can put  the string  in a variable like `$var ='<a style="display:block;width:100%;height:1px;" class="aff-ad-none"></a>' ;
  echo 'document.write('.$var.');'`
- the third way  is to cut string into 3 segmant and concat them 
  `echo 'document.write('.'<a style="display:block; width: 100%" ></a>'.');'`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use double quote inside your single quote.

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
echo 'document.write("<a style="display:block;width:100%;height:1px;" class="aff-ad-none"></a>");
window.AFF_ONLOAD = window.AFF_ONLOAD || [];window.AFF_ONLOAD.push({lkid:"11",affid:"10",size:"728*90",type:"1",language:"English",web_id:"40",version:110});
var aff_s = document.createElement("script"),aff_h = 
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];aff_s.charset = "utf-8";aff_s.async = !0;aff_s.src = "https://js.affasi.com/affasi_js.min.js";
aff_h.insertBefore(aff_s, aff_h.firstChild);
</script>';
```

You can also escape your single quote using a `\` like so : `\'`

Comment: Thanks for your answer i got the output like this: <script type="text/javascript">document.write('<a style="display:block;width:100%;height:1px;" class="aff-ad-none"></a>');
window.AFF_ONLOAD = window.AFF_ONLOAD || [];window.AFF_ONLOAD.push({lkid:"11599254",affid:"10054952",size:"728*90",type:"1",language:"English",web_id:"40",version:110});
var aff_s = document.createElement("script"),aff_h = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];aff_s.charset = "utf-8";aff_s.async = !0;aff_s.src = "https://js.affasi.com/affasi_js.min.js";
aff_h.insertBefore(aff_s, aff_h.firstChild);
</script> with \'

Comment: But cant see the output in the webpage for some reason! That is weird!

Comment: Well i can't help you with your Javascript. i don't have any context.

Comment: It was probably the content offline. I added a new one and it works thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [EOT](http://php.net/manual/ro/language.types.string.php) :

```
$string = <<<EOT
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write('<a style="display:block;width:100%;height:1px;" class="aff-
ad-none"></a>');
window.AFF_ONLOAD = window.AFF_ONLOAD || [];
window.AFF_ONLOAD.push({lkid:"11",affid:"10",size:"728*90", type:"1",language:"English",web_id:"40",version:110});
var aff_s = document.createElement("script"),aff_h = 
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];aff_s.charset = "utf-8";aff_s.async = 
!0;aff_s.src = "https://js.affasi.com/affasi_js.min.js";
aff_h.insertBefore(aff_s, aff_h.firstChild);
</script>
EOT;

echo $string;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the following.

```
<script type="text/javascript">document.write('<a style="display:block;width:100%;height:1px;" class="aff-ad-none"></a>');window.AFF_ONLOAD = window.AFF_ONLOAD || [];window.AFF_ONLOAD.push({lkid:"13172240",affid:"10068701",size:"300*250",type:"1",language:"en",web_id:"40",version:110});var aff_s = document.createElement("script"),aff_h = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];aff_s.charset = "utf-8";aff_s.async = !0;aff_s.src = "https://js.affasi.com/affasi_js.min.js";aff_h.insertBefore(aff_s, aff_h.firstChild);</script>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. It also changes the values of `lkid` and `affid`, which seems... suspicious.